# Refactor jenkins post block in a shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm desperately trying to refactor a post block for all my pipelines.
I'd like to push a slack notification after every pipeline execution.
The code for one pipeline looks like this:

```
@Library('prixan-shared-library')
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

def esJson

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Check cluster health') {
            // do some stuff
        }

        stage('Check number of elastic results') {
            // do even more stuff
        }
    }
    post {
        unstable {
            slackSend(color: 'warning', message:  "${env.JOB_NAME} - #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} Build unstable - (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)")
        }
        regression {
            slackSend(color: 'danger', message:  "${env.JOB_NAME} - #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} Regression - (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)")
        }
        fixed {
            slackSend(color: 'good', message:  "${env.JOB_NAME} - #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} Back to normal - (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)")
        }
    }
}
```

I can easily create a custom function to call or a custom block to be executed within a step block, but it seems impossible to refactor the entire post block in a customPost function => my custom block isn't accepted as a pipeline child.

```
WorkflowScript: 42: Undefined section "customPost" @ line 42, column 5.

       customPost {
```

Does anybody know if it's feasible?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show an example of how you are calling `customPost` in `post` block?
My guess is that you don't have a post condition specified under post. Ref: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post

Comment: This is the exact question I'm wondering about... did you ever figure something out?

Comment: @joshft91 unfortunately not... I'm still copy pasting from one pipeline to another

Comment: @PierreBokobza - [Here's what I'm in the middle of implementing](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5206758913998848). Probably a pretty rudimentary way of doing it, but it lets our Jenkinsfile be as small as possible and still be able to tell the status of a build. At any point in post part of the build I can get the status of the build and possibly take action on it. Cheers.